# kotlin DSL sql builder with date objects

Tags: kotlin

I am building an SQL select statement in Kotlin and I can create a simple select statement as:

```
import org.jooq.*
import org.jooq.impl.DSL
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.Instant


val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")
format.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val defaultValueLower = format.parse("1970-01-01")
val defaultValueUpper = Date.from(Instant.now())

val create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
val query: Query = create.select()
.from(DSL.table("datasets"))
.orderBy(DSL.field("id").desc())
.limit(DSL.inline(100))
```

I am using `jooq`

Now I want to add a `where` clause where the `timestamp` column is within certain dates. I have associated `Date` objects but not sure how to use it within this query builder